# Agricola - Land Parcel point

Tags: agricola, agricola-farmers-of-the-moor

The card `Land Parcel` states that:

> When you play this card, you receive 1
> forest tile that you must immediately
> place on an empty space in your
> farmyard.
>
> At the end of the game, you
> receive 2 bonus point if you have 1
> unused farmyard space, you receive -1
> bonus point if you have 2 unused
> spaces, and you receive -3 bonus point
> if you have 3 or more unused spaces.

At the end of the game, say that I have 1 unused farmyard space.

Does this mean that I will get 1 **net** point (+2 from the card bonus points and -1 because I have 1 unused farmyard space) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the rules, p8, "the [scoring] categories are scored one after another", so yes, if you consider these two categories in isolation, if you had a single unused space, you'd lose a point at the *unused farmyard spaces* scoring category stage, and then gain two in the *bonus points* category stage.

The card doesn't alter the way you score points in the *unused farmyard spaces* stage, it operates by providing you with (or costing you) bonus points. (For example, note that with this card, your first unused farmyard space, with only the two scoring effects operational, gets you a point, the second costs you three points, the third costs you four points, but the fourth only costs you one point.)

Don't forget that other cards might also add, or subtract, points for unused farmyard spaces and the game has to be designed so that all the pieces can interoperate with one another.
(For example, you might have a card that says something like "when calculating your score for unused farmyard spaces, you don't lose any points for such spaces"... in conjunction with the *Land Parcel* card, this would give you 2 points for one unused space, cost you 1 point for 2 unused spaces, and cost you 3 points for three or more unused spaces, because again the bonus points get accounted for after the unused farmyard spaces points.)

Comment: I understand the first paragraph. But in your second paragraph, you mentioned that 'the second costs you two points, the third costs you four points, but the fourth only costs you one point'. Won't the second unused space cost me 3 points (-2 from 2 unused space, -1 from the card) ?

Comment: @ryanprayogo You are correct -- I've edited my answer accordingly.